# Function which returns function scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

Ok so I've spent quite a lot of time on this, I can't seem to grasp how to do this. I do understand it quite a bit when it's a simple variable but can't seem to grasp a little more complicated problem with the same concept.

This is the simple one I understand quite a bit:

```
(define (add n)
   (lambda (x) (+ x n)))

(define total (add 5))
(total 12) => **17**
```

This is what I'm trying to achieve, when an integer is entered it should find the value of that position, I have the function that finds the position already but not sure how to implement this into the function which returns a function way:

```
(define (position N L)
  (cond ((null? L) L)
        ((= N 1) (car L))
        (else (position (- N 1) (cdr L)))))
```

For example if I enter `(define X (position '(1 5 8 2 7)))` and then input `(X 4)` it should output `2` which is at position #4. I'm sure it's something simple but I've been sitting here for a while trying to put it together but I'm not doing well. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easiest to create a second procedure:

```
(define (position L N)
  (cond ((null? L) L)
        ((= N 1) (car L))
        (else (position (cdr L) (- N 1)))))

(define (position2 L)
  (lambda (N)
    (position L N)))
```

then

```
> (define X (position2 '(1 5 8 2 7)))
> (X 4)
2
```

In Racket, you can also use `curry`:

```
> (define x (curry position '(1 5 8 2 7)))
> (x 4)
2
```

Comment: Thanks! I get it now, I was trying to implement lambda in there but it wouldn't work correctly. Why would one person choose to do this rather than call `(position '(1 5 8 2 7) 4)` Is it because in case you have to use the same list several times and so you don't have to type the list out?

Comment: @user2318083 This can come in handy with higher order procedures such as map. For example, to double every element of a list, you can say `(map (curry * 2) '(1 5 10))` in Racket which is shorter than `(map (lambda (e) (* 2 e)) '(1 5 10))`.

Answer (score 3):

As uselpa said, you could do this by defining a second procedure, but this is a fairly straightforward implementation so you could do something like this:

```
(define (position L)
  (lambda (N) 
    (cond ((null? L) '())
          ((= N 1) (car L))
          (else ((position (cdr L)) (- N 1))))))

(define X (position '(1 5 8 2 7)))
```

Here, X is defined as a `#<procedure>` bound to the function `position` with the list `L`. In the `else` statement, you see `(position (cdr L))` which is equivalent to `X`, which we follow with `(- N 1)`.

Comment: Thanks! Both of your answers combined really cleared things up for me. I was trying to understand it the way you did it but it confused me. So putting both of the answers together really made things clear :)